# Postgres sql Inner join and Delete query both are returning different results

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql

I'm using Postgres Inner join query to select some data from a table and after selecting that data I'm trying to delete that data using Delete query.
But both of the query are producing different output

I have tried following query

Select query

```
select_query = """select * from "{}" inner join "{}" on "{}".item_id = 
        "{}"."Item_ID" """.format(new_table, file_name, new_table, file_name)
cur.execute(select_query)
print(cur.rowcount)
```

Delete query

```
delete_query = """Delete from "{}" using "{}" where "{}".item_id = 
         "{}"."Item_ID" """.format(new_table, file_name, new_table, file_name)
cur.execute(delete_query)
print(cur.rowcount)
```

Output of Select Query = 1810 rows

Output of Delete Query = 1808 rows

Comment: Can you show the actual queries?

Comment: Thanks for replying got the answer has there were duplicates data in the table hence it fetched 2 rows extra